# SP2013 doesn't support resource calendar?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any other way to get that feature back? I need to create a car reservation calendar and I could really use it. I found that it is possible via JavaScript but I am new to Sharepoint so that doesn't me confident trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SP 2013, this features were excluded from the new platform. To display the missing features, you need to edit the WEBTEMP.XML file, find an element with "Group Work Site" title attribute and change its Hidden attribute from FALSE to TRUE.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588685/ReservationplusofplusresourcesplusinplusSharePoint?fid=1832374&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=26